# PHP xml parser is cutting urls inside node

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Why does parser is cutting url to this:

inside node:

```
http://img844.imageshack.us/content.php?page=done&amp;l=img844/4783/php4dd.jpg
```

after parse:

[done_page] => l=img844/8828/php4e8.jpg

```
 private function _parse($result)
 {

  $XMLparser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');



  xml_set_element_handler(
   $XMLparser,
   Array($this, 'startElement'),
   Array($this, 'endElement')
  );

  xml_set_character_data_handler($XMLparser, Array($this, 'stringElement'));






  if (!xml_parse($XMLparser, $result)) {

   echo '<br>XML Error: '.xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($XMLparser));
   echo ' at line '.xml_get_current_line_number($XMLparser);
   exit();

  }

  print_r($this->parsed_results);


  xml_parser_free($XMLparser);

 }

 public function stringElement($parser, $str)
 {

  if(strlen(trim($str)) > 0)
  {

   $this->parsed_results[$this->current_name] = $str;  

  }  

 }


 public function startElement($parser, $name, $attributes)
 {

  $this->current_name = $name;

 }


 public function endElement($parser, $name)
 {



 }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><links>
    <image_link>http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/8828/php4e8.jpg</image_link>
    <thumb_link>http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/8828/php4e8.th.jpg</thumb_link>
    <ad_link>http://img844.imageshack.us/my.php?image=php4e8.jpg</ad_link>
    <thumb_exists>yes</thumb_exists>
    <total_raters>0</total_raters>
    <ave_rating>0.0</ave_rating>

    <image_location>img844/8828/php4e8.jpg</image_location>
    <thumb_location>img844/8828/php4e8.th.jpg</thumb_location>
    <server>img844</server>
    <image_name>php4e8.jpg</image_name>
    <done_page>http://img844.imageshack.us/content.php?page=done&amp;l=img844/8828/php4e8.jpg</done_page>
    <resolution>468x458</resolution>

    <filesize>118347</filesize>
    <image_class>r</image_class>
</links>
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the XML being parsed as well?  This smells like an entity issue.

Comment: Suuuure thing. Added at the bottom. ;)

Comment: Maybe raw xml should be passed through some decoding function before proceeding to parse? It's my first work with xml actually. :)

Any advice would be awesome.

Comment: xml is comming from curl request result, working with curl first time as well. Maybe it's because some of curl parameters is set wrong? I can post curl request as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser may have returned the text as two contiguous text nodes, resulting in `stringElement` being called twice.  The second call would have overwritten the text from the first text node.  Try changing `stringElement` so that it concatenates the input to any existing text and see if that returns the entire string.

On second examination, I'm pretty sure the parser returns the `&amp;` entity reference as a separate node, so you may have to reassemble all the text yourself.  Depending on the parser implementation, the entity reference may be a different kind of node, so you will have to research what your particular parser does with entity references.

Comment: Great idea! I'll try to concatenate the node. Yea i think that's why it shows only the last part of url.

Btw i'm using built in php parser, i haven't written my own parser.

Btw is it better to user php5 DocumentDOM class to work with xml?

Comment: Sorry, I know a lot about XML but almost nothing about PHP :-)

Comment: yea you were right
i have added <br> tag between $str and that's what it printed out:

 
<br />DONE_PAGE:<br />http://img844.imageshack.us/content.php?page=done<br />&<br />l=img844/3939/php50a.jpg<br />

Comment: @Beck: `DOMDocument` offers more functionalty & convenience. the `xmlparser`-function collection is more suitable for either large documents (less memory needed) or working on just a small subset of a document (looking for a specific node & then forgetting about the rest of the document). For creating simple XML documents or just reading a list of values from XML without much DOM manipulation or namespaces, `SimpleXML` would be easiest. When looking at the document in the question, I'd advise `SimpleXML`.